# Can't jump properly whilst holding ctrl to sprint in Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

If I'm using the ctrl button to sprint and I try to jump, the jumping action gets delayed by about 2 seconds.

Previously this has not been the case and I have been able to jump and hold sprint before. I have not purchased a new keyboard or made any changes to my existing keyboard. Is this a common problem? What can I do to fix this delay?

Comment: What does "previously" mean? Which version did you play before and which version do you play now?

Comment: I have not changed the version I play on or anything. It was just one day, I logged on and couldn't jump whilst holding ctrl.

Comment: Then it's probably something in your system that has changed. New keyboard, different setting, some accessibility thing activated accidentally, …